# Client/browser how to set standard security headers? (https server on wss connection)

Tags: node.js, security, https, websocket, http-headers

Im using https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhttps for my node.js application.

I want to send response headers to the client side

- **Strict-Transport-Security** enforces secure (HTTP over SSL/TLS) connections to the server
- **X-Frame-Options** provides clickjacking protection
- **X-XSS-Protection** enables the Cross-site scripting (XSS) filter built into most recent web browsers
- **X-Content-Type-Options** prevents browsers from MIME-sniffing a response away from the declared content-type
- **Content-Security-Policy** prevents a wide range of attacks, including Cross-site scripting and other cross-site injections

https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-security-checklist/ states that I could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet but I am not using `express` and never wan't to.

**The https server is for a wss websocket**. I'm checking *certain things* on upgrade to see if I want to accept the connection or not (as part of *onion layered* security)

```
var server=(require('hardhttps').createServer({key:pem.key,cert:pem.cert,ca:[pem.ca],passphrase:pem.pass})).listen(port);
server.on("upgrade",function(req,socket,head){// happens before the websockect receives on `connection`
    var ip=req.headers['x-forwarded-for']||req.connection.remoteAddress||req.socket.remoteAddress||req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;//got their ip (can compare with previous visitor)
    });
var wss=new WebSocketServer({
    server:server
,   verifyClient:function(info,cb){
        //could verify ip here and block the connection from happening...
        if(('https://'+host)===(info.req.headers.origin)){cb(true);}
        }});
wss.on('connection',function(socket){var ip=socket._socket.remoteAddress//....
```

I think I ether have to set the headers when I start the server or inside the upgrade, but I can't see any examples of this.

If I search for this I find that people are talking about custom headers a lot but the above headers I specifically want to set are not custom at all, at least to http! A websocket is just a wrapper on http (as I understand).

Comment: Those are response headers, not request headers

Comment: how can I use them inside the upgrade?

    `socket.writeHead(200, {"Strict-Transport-Security": "true"});`
    `socket.pipe(socket);`

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I updated my question to asking about response headers (thank you for helping)

Answer (score 0):

For a `node.js` application **without** using any external framework e.g. `express`:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((request, response) => {

    request.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);

    // for this simple example I am not including the data event
    // e.g. if the request contains data in the body

    }).on('end', () => {

       response.on('error', (err) => {
           console.error(err);
       });

      // you can explicitly set your headers with setHeader or 
      // use writeHead as a "shortcut" to include the statusCode. 
      // Note writeHead won't cache results internally
      // and if used in conjuction with setHeader will take some sort of "precedence"

      response.writeHead(200, {
          "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000"

           // other security headers here...
      });

      response.end("<html><body><h1>Hello, Security Headers!</h1></body></html>");

  });
}).listen(8080);
```

[See the node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) for more details on setting headers on the response object